# What is expected token for declare spark submit (python script) in shell script with specific directory input?

Tags: python, bash, shell, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

**Summary:**

What is expected token for declare spark submit (python script) in shell script with specific directory input? What punctuation should I use?

I already try `<` , but it doesn't work

**Detail:**

I try to give as much as detail possible on my case to understand my situation. My input is in

`sys.argv[1]` for `dataset_1`, `dataset_2`, `dataset_3`

`sys.argv[2]` for `dataset_4`

`sys.argv[3]` for `dataset_5`

`sys.argv[4]` for `dataset_6`

My Output

`sys.argv[5]`

Additional input in

`sys.argv[6]` for year

`sys.argv[7]` for month

Here is part of the script, the file name is `cs_preDeploy.py`

```
import os
import sys

#/tmp/sdsid/encrypted_dataset/ae80ead7-bcf1-43ca-a888-03f6ba48f4b9/0/dataset_1/year=2021/month=1
input_path_1 = os.path.join(sys.argv[1], 'dataset_1')

#/tmp/sdsid/encrypted_dataset/ae80ead7-bcf1-43ca-a888-03f6ba48f4b9/0/dataset_2/year=2021/month=1
input_path_2 = os.path.join(sys.argv[1], 'dataset_2')

#/tmp/sdsid/encrypted_dataset/ae80ead7-bcf1-43ca-a888-03f6ba48f4b9/0/dataset_3/year=2021/month=1
input_path_3 = os.path.join(sys.argv[1], 'dataset_3')

# /tmp/sdsid/encrypted_dataset/328b7446-1862-4489-b1b4-57fa55fe556a/0/dataset_4/year=2021/month=2
input_path_4 = os.path.join(sys.argv[2], 'dataset_4')

# /tmp/sdsid/encrypted_dataset/3119bdd9-c7a8-44c3-b3f8-e49a86261106/0/dataset_5/year=2021/month=2
input_path_5 = os.path.join(sys.argv[3], 'dataset_5')

# /tmp/sdsid/encrypted_dataset/efc84a0f-52e9-4dff-91a1-56e1d7aa02cb/0/dataset_6/year=2021/month=2
input_path_6 = os.path.join(sys.argv[4], 'dataset_6')

output_path = sys.argv[5]

#query_year = sys.argv[6]
#query_month = sys.argv[7]
#For looping year month

if len(sys.argv) > 7:
    year = int(sys.argv[6]) # year
    month = int(sys.argv[7]) # month
else:
    month_obs = datetime.datetime.today()
    month = month_obs.month
    year = month_obs.year
```

Here's my first try

```
[sdsid@user algorithm]$ PYSPARK_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3 ./bin/spark-submit \
> --master yarn \
> --deploy-mode cluster \
> --driver-memory 16g \
> --executor-memory 16g \
> --num-executors 5 \
> --executor-cores 1 \
> ./home/sdsid/algorithm/cs_preDeploy.py
```

The Output

```
-bash: ./bin/spark-submit: No such file or directory
```

Here's the second try, I put year parameter for `sys.argv[6]` is 2021 and `sys.argv[7]` is 7 (July)

```
[sdsid@user algorithm]$ nohup spark-sumbit cs_preDeploy.py </tmp/sdsid/sample_dataset/></tmp/sdsid/sample_dataset/dataset_4></tmp/sdsid/sample_dataset/dataset_5></tmp/sdsid/sample_dataset/dataset_6></tmp/sdsid/sample_output/dataset_output/> 2021 7
```

The error message

```
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `<'
```

The Third Try

```
[sdsid@user algorithm]$ nohup spark-sumbit cs_preDeploy.py <"/tmp/sdsid/sample_dataset/"><"/tmp/sdsid/sample_dataset/dataset_4"><"/tmp/sdsid/sample_dataset/dataset_5"><"/tmp/sdsid/sample_dataset/dataset_6"><"/tmp/sdsid/sample_output/dataset_output/"> 2021 7
```

The error message

```
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `<'
```

Comment: Hello, these command line errors are not related to spark, the only relevant tags for me are bash/shell, and you should find basic explanations about these bash errors on the internet (basically the shell does not find spark-submit in the specified location and `<` and `>` are special characters)

Comment: @bonnal-enzo Just anticipating, probably hadoop has spesific syntax for this

Comment: `<` and `>` in bash indicate redirection (stdin or stdout).  The only way to get this to be a real command is to put the `<` and `>` within `"` (double-quotes).  But remember that your script will need to handle these characters as well (i.e. double quote all variable referencing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `-bash: ./bin/spark-submit: No such file or directory` 
  a. Put here full path like /folder1/folder2/bin/spark-submit as as ./
  means current directory and depending where you are now such path may not exist.

  b.Or add spark submit to [PATH](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26047/how-to-correctly-add-a-path-to-path) so you may run spark-submit without path
- `` -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `<' `` 
  Use quotes to pass parameters as **'<>'** are special characters : 
  `spark-sumbit cs_preDeploy.py '<"/tmp/sdsid/sample_dataset/">' 2021 7` 
  Use single quotes '' if you have double quotes "" inside of the string
  `spark-sumbit cs_preDeploy.py '<param with special characters>' 2021 7` 
  Use double quotes with escape \ if you have varibles inside 
  `spark-sumbit cs_preDeploy.py "$Variable plus some quotes \" inside \" " 2021 7` 
  [image] "
- Please reffer the link how to submit apps to run [py spark](https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-submit-command/#spark-submit-python-pyspark), here a lot of examples